# Where to get all possible tags/values for "svn status --xml"?

Tags: xml, svn, status

`svn status --xml` prints all files status and it's more much useful than parsing `svn status` output.

1. Is there a list of all possible tags/sections in XML file and their values?
   I can read SVN sources but its time consuming and a dirty method.
2. Is it possible to find clean map from `svn status --xml` values to `svn status` status characters also?

Answer (score 7):

I've found Schema file for status command so its a fast answer.

File placed in SVN source tree there:

```
subversion/svn/schema/status.rnc
```

Answer (score 6):

It is available here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/schema/status.rnc?view=markup

The list for the current trunk of SVN is:

- added
- conflicted
- deleted
- external
- ignored
- incomplete
- merged
- missing
- modified
- none
- normal
- obstructed
- replaced
- unversioned